# Higlight a specific cell based on ADDRESS() return value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I want to give a style (highlight) a specific cell based on a date value. This date is, say, in cell
A1.

To achieve this, I thought I would calculate the address of the cell I want to style with the ADDRESS function. Let's say I want to highlight cell C3, I would then use:

```
=ADDRESS( (DAY(A1) + 2); (MONTH(A1) + 2) )
```

Which returns $C$3.

But obviously I am missing something because I can't find a way to use this returned value. I tried to apply a conditional formatting and use something like

```
=CELL("address")=ADDRESS((DAY(A1)+2);(MONTH(A1)+2))
```

With no luck.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm really confused, What are you trying to do? Check to see if the.. reference in column C is `A1`? For all of column C?

Comment: If cell A1 contains date 01/01/2000, cell C3 should be highlighted; if cell A1 contains date 02/01/2000, cell C4 (because C4 = $C$(3+1)); if cell A1 contains date 01/02/2000, cell D3 (because D3 = $(C+1)$3)).

Comment: I still don't get it, can you take a screenshot of a sheet with how you want it to be set up?

Comment: Your `CELL("address"` version can work, although you need to reference C3 in the CELL function and use $A$1 to fix the reference cell in ADDRESS function - like this: `=CELL("address";C3)=ADDRESS(DAY($A$1)+2;MONTH($A$1)+2)` - note semi-colons to match your regional settings.......but I prefer CallumDA33's approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. Highlight cell **C3:D4** (as per example) and add conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=AND(ROW(C3)-2=DAY($A$1),COLUMN(C3)-2=MONTH($A$1))
```

I have tested this and it works as described so let me know if you have any problems.

*Note: this formula excludes year as a factor, so 1/1/2000 would highlight cell C3, as would 1/1/2015*

[image]

Copy the formatting from cells **C3:D4** down and accross to increase the range that is affected by the date value in cell **A1**